# java Processbuilder - exec a file which is not in path on OS X

Tags: java, macos, exec

Okay i'm trying to make [ChucK](http://chuck.cs.princeton.edu/) available in exported Processing sketches, i.e. if i export an app from Processing, the ChucK VM binary will be executed from inside the app. So as a user of said app you don't need to worry about ChucK being in your path at all.

Right now i'm generating and executing a bash script file, but this way i don't get any console output from ChucK back into Processing:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "[to where the Chuck executable is located]"
./chuck --kill
killall chuck # just to make sure
./chuck chuckScript1.ck cuckScriptn.ck
```

then

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 777 "+scriptPath);
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(scriptPath);
```

This works but i want to run ChucK directly from Processing instead, but can't get it to execute:

```
String chuckPath = "[folder in which the chuck executable is located]"
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder
                              (chuckPath+"/chuck", "test.ck");

        final Process process = builder.start();
        InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) println(line);
        println("done chuckin'! exitValue: " + process.exitValue());
```

Sorry if this is newbie style :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder
                              (chuckPath+"/chuck", chuckPath+"/test.ck");
```

the args all need an absolute path.

Comment: Please edit your question and do NOT provide more infos in an answer.

Comment: i've put this in an answer because this works. Since the arg to chuck is a file itself, it needed the full path as well.